# Error while trying to open sugar DE app bundles (.xo) on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux

How can I do just what I wrote in the title? A few years ago I used a OLPC XO laptop, with sugar desktop environment installed, and I want to feel nostalgic again so I tried to download sugar, at start all seemed to work (I installed using the official Arch Linux wiki method, using python2, the python3 doesn't seem to work), but when trying to install some .xo bundle packages they didn't open, I tried using some scripts I found on GitHub but some of the packages are Deprecated so I can't install them (others are simply not available), this is what I get when trying to install some packages:

```
xa_xo: error while loading shared libraries: libSDL_image-1.2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Exited with status 127, pid 89171 activity_id a3fae722437c027226a127b31aa927f6f540ebf3
```

Is there anyway to fix this? Or do I have to emulate the OS and flashing Sugar on a stick
(SOAS)

Answer (score 0):

Install [SDL 1.2.15-14 from the AUR](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/sdl/) and report back.  There may be more libraries needed.